# What are the important considerations when choosing a pass transistor and bias resistor for a buck regulator?

Tags: transistors, buck, switch-mode-power-supply, npn

The [MC34063 datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC34063A-D.PDF) shows this diagram for a buck configuration with an external (NPN) transistor (in order to be able to handle higher loads than 750mA):

[image: External NPN transistor]

Neither the datasheet nor the application note provide any guidance in choosing the transistor or the bias resistor connected to it. What are the important criteria when choosing a pass transistor, other than current capacity, and how should the bias resistor on the base of the transistor be sized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than current handling, I would look for a transistor that has a high DC current gain so that it saturates easily, with a low base current, and one that has a low \$V_{CE}\$ (sat). That is to say, when it is fully turned on, the voltage drop across it is low.

I don't know what additional current handling you are looking for, but I have a suggestion. Check out the [2SD882](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00062867.pdf) medium power NPN transistor. I needed a transistor with decent DC gain, current handling and low \$V_{CE}\$ (sat). After quite a search through numerous data sheets, I settled on that one. I managed to get my hands on a bunch of Panasonic made in Japan ones, and the \$H_{FE}\$ of all of them measured over 360. (This is probably no important in this application.)

The PNP complement of this transistor is [2SB772](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00062866.pdf).

Now let's look at the resistors. \$R_{SC}\$ is a current sensing resistor. This will have some tiny value, a fraction of an ohm. The value is important because it determines the trigger threshold for turning on the outboard transistor. The datasheet doesn't give a value for that in your particular circuit, but I think the value from Fig. 11 of 0.33 ohms can be reused for the Fig. 11a circuit.

Then there is the base resistor on the transistor. Its value is does not appear critical.  But note that this resistor will function as the emitter feedback resistor for the switch transistor inside (Q2). The feedback which it develops oppposes the turning on of the internal transistors.

There is a reason why Fig. 11a is called "NPN switch"  while 11b is "Saturated PNP Switch". The PNP topology does not develop feedback. The switch emitter is simply grounded.

The PNP looks like the superior circuit; I would go for that one.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think the PNP circuit is superior? Also, it includes two additional resistors, instead of the NPN circuit's one; what about their purpose and values?

Comment: I think that because the circuit avoids adding a feedback resistor onto the switch emitter. Those two additional resistors are quite isolated from the circuit. The two external resistors form a voltage divider. When the switch is shut off, nothing flows through the resistors and so the base of the PNP is pulled toward Vin and it is cut off. When the switch is turned on, the bottom of this divider is pulled low. The voltage between the resistors, and the available base current should be such that the given transistor is driven into hard saturation.

Comment: I should clarify that first comment. Without the emitter resistor, there is no feedback into the switch which opposes the state of being turned on. I.e. the PNP circuit avoids any risk of using those transistors in the active region. That kind of thing probably pointless because, to my understanding, the current control is achieved in this IC by modulating the frequency/duration of the switching behavior, not the operation of transistors in the active region. Toggling between cutoff and hard saturation is superior because it minimizes heat dissipation in the transistors.

Comment: Didn't you say the value of the pulldown in the NPN configuration is not critical, though? I don't fully understand under what circumstances the NPN could be less than fully saturated, and why that can't apply to the PNP configuration with the same problem. And I thus don't know how to size the resistor divider in the PNP configuration, either. :/

Comment: I was wrong to say that; the value of the NPN's base resistor is important, but it's hard to put a number on it without knowing the internal resistor (spanning the BE junction of Q1). You don't want it too high because it develops a feedback voltage, and Q1 rides on top of it. The PNP voltage divider resistors are easy to choose. Say 1K/1K. They have to be small enough to allow enough base current (and the higher the \$H_{FE}\$ of your transistor, the less base current is needed to saturate it) and you want the top resistor to have more than enough V to forward-bias the base-emitter junction.

Comment: The PNP circuit is quite different because its biasing is decoupled from causing feedback into the Q1 circuit. It is in the collector branch of Q1, not in the emitter branch.

Comment: It'll prove helpful if you search various IC manufacturer's web sites for "external switch" regulator ICs - and especially read the corresponding application notes. Those will contain information about the pros and cons of external MOSFETs and BJTs in their p and n or pnp and npn styles. Material published more than 10 years ago might be especially good, because since then, it's pretty much all n-channel MOSFETs. Those are better suited for the task and ICs now take the extra effort to drive them even as high-side switches.

Answer (score 2):

Some background: Switching supplies are good because the switching transistors are, ideally, at zero current while off and they are at zero voltage while on. Both times, one of the numbers for V or I in the equation V*I=P  are zero, making the transistor losses P also zero.

The transistor will have low conduction ("on") losses if it has a low saturation voltage V<sub>CE,sat</sub>; we can't really get V=0, but we can get close to this design goal. (V*I=P will be low because V will almost be at zero.)

While the transistor switches from on to off or from off to on, neither V or I will be close to zero. Thus, you want to keep the switching time as short as reasonably possible. For the transistor, this means: It will have low switching losses if it turns on and off fast. Generally a problem with bipolar transistors, but you might want to look for transistors designed for switching applications; these ususally have a comparatively high transition frequency f<sub>t</sub>.

The resistor between base and ground actually is not a bias resistor but a pull-down resistor. The IC can only pull the base high (i.e. bring the external transistor to conduction). Once the IC stops pulling high (= stops providing base drive current), it is the pull down resistor's job to bring and keep the base low and keep the transistor off. Keeping it off is not so much of a problem as bringing it there. The lower the resistor's value, the quicker the transistor will be brought from its on-state to its off-state, minimizing the losses during each turn-off process. Then again, if the resistor is too low, it will demand and waste extra current from the IC's switching pin (#2) while on.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a ballpark value for the pulldown? If not, how should I determine the correct value? And are you aware of any go-to transistors for this sort of application?

Comment: I have not seen a switching converter use a BJT in a long time;  MOSFETs have taken over.  There may not even be any "go-to" BJTs these days.  For the pull-down, I suppose you would find a value for the charge stored in the base of the BJT and choose a pull-down resistance to remove that charge in a time much less than your switching period.

Comment: @ArtBrown - The switcher in use is an old one, [this PCN](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/pcn.do?id=4492) is from 1999 so the part is probably close to 15 years old.  A very good point!

Comment: Is there any reason I couldn't use a MOSFET instead, then?

Comment: Unfortunately, the IC doesn't look like it can drive a MOSFET directly.  Maybe someone else can see a clever way to do it...

Comment: @ArtBrown I don't see the difficulty in driving an enhancement mode MOSFET which has bipolar-like, zero-based biasing (cut off at VGS zero, turns on at some positive VGS, like 4V). Might you be thinking of depletion mode MOSFETs?

Comment: @Kaz, I guess I'm not sure what circuit you're proposing.  If an N-channel enhanced mode MOSFET is just dropped in, in place of the BJT, I don't see how you would maintain a positive gate-source voltage in the ON state.  In any case, I'm certainly not claiming it can't be done, just that it's not obvious to me.

Comment: This is true. Basically in the above circuit, we have an emitter-follower arrangement. The ability to drive the MOSFET would depend on the voltage generated by the inner "box" which drives the transistor pair, which is an unknown. I think the PNP circuit (11b) has a better chance for MOSFET substitution, with a P-channel. When the switch turns on to saturation of Q1, you have nearly the full voltage range (minus VCE(sat) of Q1 and the current sensor) making it possible to establish the 5 volt gate-source or whatever is needed.